# How to cache the gridview's columns collection and call the following method in Page_Load

Tags: mysql, asp.net, excel

i have a gridview which hold dynamic data depends on event button and i want that created dynamic data to be exported via excel, I've search all over the net found some interesting technique for gridview that holds dynamic data,

The method is to cache the gridview's columns collection and call the following method in Page_load. Below is the script, and i just wanna ask and help where to put this exactly in my form, i am new in ASP and badly freaking out now..

```
protected void restore_columns() {
    DataControlFieldCollection columns = (DataControlFieldCollection)Cache["cols"];
    gvSchluessel.Columns.Clear(); // gvSchluessel is the GridView
    foreach (DataControlField field in columns) {
        gvSchluessel.Columns.Add(field);
        if (field.GetType() == typeof(TemplateField)) {
            TemplateField tf = (TemplateField)field;
            int i = gvSchluessel.Columns.IndexOf(tf);
            if (tf.HeaderTemplate != null) {
                tf.HeaderTemplate.InstantiateIn(gvSchluessel.HeaderRow.Cells[i]);
            }
            foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSchluessel.Rows)
            {
                if (tf.ItemTemplate != null) {
                    tf.ItemTemplate.InstantiateIn(row.Cells[i]);
                }
            }
            if (tf.FooterTemplate != null) {
                tf.FooterTemplate.InstantiateIn(gvSchluessel.FooterRow.Cells[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```